# Plotly barchart (graph object GO) different marker pattern shape depending on the specific column value

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, plotly-python

[Solved by @Rob Raymond second answer]

I have been strugling with defining pattern shape source (specific column values).

I want to define pattern shape ("//", '.', etc.) based on column name 'size'.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
animals=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys', 'rats']
size=['big', 'medium', 'medium', 'small']
number=[20, 14, 23, 5]
columns = ['animal','size','number','test']

df = pd.DataFrame({'animals':animals, 'size':size,'number':number})
fig = go.Figure([go.Bar( x=df['animals'].values.tolist(), y=df['number'].values.tolist())])
fig.update_traces(marker_pattern_shape=['.', '\\','+','/'])
fig.show()
```

|  | animals | size | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | giraffes | big | 20 |
| 2 | orangutans | medium | 14 |
| 3 | monkeys | medium | 23 |
| 4 | rats | small | 5 |

[image: Simple barchart]

I have been trying lines below:

`fig.update_traces(marker_pattern_shape=['.', '\\','+','/'], marker_pattern = {'shape':['+', '\\']})`

`go.Bar(..., marker = {'pattern':'.'}, ...)`



PS. I am forced to use plotly GO not ploty express. Long story.

### UPDATE after @Rob Raymond answer.

It is working for first solution, but it is not working for the Frankenstein, which I have created. Below more complex minimal reproducible example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
animals=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys', 'rats', "mice"]
size=['big', 'medium', 'medium', 'small', "small"]
number=[20, 14, 23, 5, 4]
animalId=[1,2,3,4,5]
colorPlotly = ['lightslategrey','red','black', 'saddlebrown','grey']

df = pd.DataFrame({'animals':animals, 'size':size,'number':number,'animalId':animalId, 'colorPlotly':colorPlotly})
fig = go.Figure()
for id in animalId:
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x=df[df['animalId']==id]['animals'],
            y=df[df['animalId']==id]['number'],
                name = id,
                    marker_color=df[df['animalId']==id]['colorPlotly']))

fig.update_traces(marker_pattern_shape=df["size"].map({'big':".", 'medium':"\\", 'medium':"+", 'small':"/"}))
fig.show()
```

|  | animals | size | number | colorPlotly | animalId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | giraffes | big | 20 | lightslategrey | 1 |
| 2 | orangutans | medium | 14 | red | 2 |
| 3 | monkeys | medium | 23 | black | 3 |
| 4 | rats | small | 4 | saddlebrown | 4 |
| 5 | mices | small | 5 | grey | 5 |

[image]

Comment: You're saying `PS. I am forced to use plotly GO not ploty express. Long story.` What's the story?

Comment: In certain point I have reached mine or plotly express library limitations. I have large number of categories, which I wanted to show. In some point I wanted to order bar charts, while it was being stacked. I failed. TBH this would be a topic for whole new stackoverflow question. I have asked python colleagues from work and we decided to go around with add_trace to manually control the stack of bars order. Function "category_orders" was not working at all for sorting the stacked bars based on different column values.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I'm always interested in hearing about how people use plotly, and the possible limitations they face. Please do consider writing that up as its own question, though!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Due to the fact that i will have to make minimal reproducible example it may take a while, but I will try to create a post soon.

Comment: If your main challenge in creating a reproducbiel example is a large enough dataset, you can take a look at how I built the dataframe for my second suggestion in [Dash DropDown closes after click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69535813/dash-dropdown-closes-after-click/69546868#69546868)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- simple case of using https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html
- have updated you sample data as well, so there are two small animals

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
animals=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys', 'rats', "mice"]
size=['big', 'medium', 'medium', 'small', "small"]
number=[20, 14, 23, 5, 4]

df = pd.DataFrame({'animals':animals, 'size':size,'number':number})
fig = go.Figure([go.Bar( x=df['animals'], y=df['number'])])
fig.update_traces(marker_pattern_shape=df["size"].map({'big':".", 'medium':"\\", 'medium':"+", 'small':"/"}))
fig.show()
```

#### using multiple traces

- build a mapping (**dict**) between animal names and valid *pattern shape*
- use this when constructing figure

```
animal_map = {k:v for k, v in zip(animals, np.tile(['/', '\\', 'x', '-', '|', '+', '.'], 3)[:len(animals)])}
fig = go.Figure()
for id in animalId:
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Bar(
            x=df[df["animalId"] == id]["animals"],
            y=df[df["animalId"] == id]["number"],
            name=id,
            marker_color=df[df["animalId"] == id]["colorPlotly"],
            marker_pattern_shape=df.loc[df["animalId"] == id, "animals"].map(animal_map)
        )
    )
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick respond!  Indeed it is working for first example, but for the more complex one it is still do not working.  Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: updated - there is no relationship between a row and a trace, hence reason you code does not work.  it's not clear to me if you want to use *animal* or *size* to map to a **pattern shape**